Plotting Chladni pattern
Hi fellow mathematicians, I'm trying to simulate a 2d Chladni pattern in Matlab and Maple. Using Fourier series, I get:
Solution for rectangular membrane
However, comparing the result to previous 9 year post:Here
The person who simulated the Chladni pattern in Mathematica used a different formula:
$cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})*cos(\frac{m\pi y}{L})-cos(\frac{m\pi x}{L})*cos(\frac{n\pi y}{L})$=0 
Why is there a huge difference when I used Fourier series to find the general solution? and How do I plot my discovered general solution?

How can we be useful faced to your impressive formulas without any accompanying text explaining what is what ?
